# local gulp not found after installing globally and locally

Tags: gulp

I have installed `gulp` both globally

```
sudo npm install --global gulp-cli
```

and locally

```
npm install --save-dev gulp
```

`/usr/local/bin/gulp` exists, and `./node_modules/gulp` and `./node_modules/gulp-cli` exist.

When I try to run `gulp` on the command line, I get the common error

```
$ gulp
[00:55:43] Local gulp not found in ~/dev/myProj/play-java-seed
[00:55:43] Try running: npm install gulp
```

One thing that I noticed is that if I run `gulp` in some random directory (~/foo), the error message is that the local gulp is not found in that directory.  If I run it from the correct directory (~/dev/myProj/play-java-seed/ui) then the error references the parent directory.

There is in fact no gulp installed in the directory in the error message; it is installed on directory lower.

`/usr/local/bin/gulp` is a symlink to a file with these contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

'use strict';

require('../')();
```

Is the `..` in that file correct?  It seems strange, but I have not looked at it closely before.

If the OS matters, I am running 32 bit Ubuntu 16.04.

`devDependencies` in my `package.json` includes both `gulp` and `gulp-cli`

Comment: is there a `gulpfile.js` in the folder?

Comment: There is a gulpfile.js in the folder with node_modules.

Comment: I also look at my gulp installation on a Mac, where gulp works as expected.  There, `/usr/local/bin/gulp` was a symlink to a file that had about 200 lines of code and looked like what I would expect.  This contrasts with the non-working Linux version, which does not look at first glance like it should work at all, although I can imagine that the require somehow does magic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rico Kahler had the correct answer in his comment.

When I looked at the machine (instead of going off of my memory), I saw that the gulp file was one directory higher than it should have been.

The error message did have a clue toward this: it gave the directory holding the gulpfile, not the current directory.